Im getting "socket hang up" error when running Appium test on an Android Emulator via Github Actions
I am trying to run a simple Appium test on on an emulator via Github Actions and I am getting the following error
Encountered internal error running command: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to the remote server. Original error: socket hang up

From the logs I can see that the session is being created and the test started running
[UiAutomator2] Starting 'com.app.mobileapp/com.app.mobileapp.MainActivity and waiting for 'com.app.mobileapp/com.app.mobileapp.MainActivity'
[ADB] Running '/usr/local/lib/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am start -n com.app.mobileapp/com.app.mobileapp.MainActivity -S'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /appium/device/pixel_ratio] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8210/session/ae5e0d73-b180-4d23-87a0-64f1d888cd50/appium/device/pixel_ratio] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"ae5e0d73-b180-4d23-87a0-64f1d888cd50","value":2.625}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/appium/device/system_bars' to command name 'getSystemBars'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /appium/device/system_bars] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8210/session/ae5e0d73-b180-4d23-87a0-64f1d888cd50/appium/device/system_bars] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"ae5e0d73-b180-4d23-87a0-64f1d888cd50","value":{"statusBar":63}}
[WD Proxy] Matched '/window/current/size' to command name 'getWindowSize'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /window/current/size] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8210/session/ae5e0d73-b180-4d23-87a0-64f1d888cd50/window/current/size] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"ae5e0d73-b180-4d23-87a0-64f1d888cd50","value":{"height":1794,"width":1080}}
[AppiumDriver@f7f8] New AndroidUiautomator2Driver session created successfully, session b08f4835-80fb-4cec-a76b-f03294e49644 added to master session list
[AppiumDriver@f7f8] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1719140225284 (10:57:05 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time))
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@f565 (b08f4835)] Cached the protocol value 'W3C' for the new session b08f4835-80fb-4cec-a76b-f03294e49644
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@f565 (b08f4835)] Responding to client with driver.createSession() result: {"capabilities":{"platform":"LINUX","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"appuium:newCommandTimeout":"600","platformName":"Android","automationName":"UiAutomator2","deviceName":"Nexus_6P_API_33","androidInstallTimeout":240000,"uiautomator2ServerInstallTimeout":240000,"adbExecTimeout":240000,"app":"/home/runner/work/app-testing/app-testing/nativeApps/android/app.apk","appPackage":"com.app.mobileapp","appActivity":"com.app.mobileapp.MainActivity","skipDeviceInitialization":true,"appWaitForLaunch":false,"systemPort":8210,"logLevel":"debug"},"appuium:newCommandTimeout":"600","platformName":"Android","automationName":"UiAutomator2","deviceName":"emulator-5554","androidInstallTimeout":240000,"uiautomator2ServerInstallTimeout":240000,"adbExecTimeout":240000,"app":"/home/runner/work/app-testing/app-testing/nativeApps/android/app.apk","appPackage":"com.app.mobil...
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 200 86035 ms - 1536 
[b08f4835][HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/b08f4835-80fb-4cec-a76b-f03294e49644/element {"using":"xpath","value":"//android.widget.ImageView[@resource-id=\"appHeaderLogo\"]"}
[b08f4835][AndroidUiautomator2Driver@f565 (b08f4835)] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["xpath","//android.widget.ImageView[@resource-id=\"appHeaderLogo\"]","b08f4835-80fb-4cec-a76b-f03294e49644"]
[b08f4835][AndroidUiautomator2Driver@f565 (b08f4835)] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, css selector, -android uiautomator
[b08f4835][AndroidUiautomator2Driver@f565 (b08f4835)] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
[b08f4835][WD Proxy] Matched '/element' to command name 'findElement'
[b08f4835][WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /element] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8210/session/ae5e0d73-b180-4d23-87a0-64f1d888cd50/element] with body: {"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.widget.ImageView[@resource-id=\"appHeaderLogo\"]","context":"","multiple":false}
[Instrumentation] INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=Process crashed.
[Instrumentation] INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
[Instrumentation] The process has exited with code 0
[b08f4835][WD Proxy] socket hang up
[b08f4835][AndroidUiautomator2Driver@f565 (b08f4835)] Encountered internal error running command: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to the remote server. Original error: socket hang up

Here is the config file
module.exports = {
  user: {
    environment: 'ci',
    email: 'ci@app.com',
    code: '555555',
  },
  capabilities: {
    'appium:platformName': 'Android',
    'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
    'appium:deviceName': 'Nexus_6P_API_33',
    'appium:androidInstallTimeout': '240000',
    'appium:uiautomator2ServerInstallTimeout': '240000',
    'appium:adbExecTimeout': '240000',
    'appium:app': getAppPath(),
    'appium:appPackage': 'com.app.mobileapp',
    'appium:appActivity': 'com.app.mobileapp.MainActivity',
    'appium:skipDeviceInitialization': true,
    'appium:appWaitForLaunch': false,
    'appium:systemPort': 8210,
    'appuium:newCommandTimeout': '600',
    'appium:logLevel': 'debug'
  },
  wdOpts: {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 4723,
    path: '/wd/hub',
    logLevel: 'info',
  },
};

function getAppPath() {
  if (process.env.GITHUB_ACTIONS) {
    return '/home/runner/work/app-testing/app-testing/nativeApps/android/app.apk'; // GitHub Actions
  } else {
    return '/Users/ghassangharzuzy/app-testing/nativeApps/android/app.apk'; // Local
  }
}

I was hoping to run Appium test on an Android Emulator via Github Actions and make it pass.
